# Need a JS to return to h5 value in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to return the value for the top level h5 in a large dropdown menu. If someone clicks on Power Tools, I need a function to return System. I have no idea where to start on this and could really use some help. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code of one of the dropdown menus.

```
<div class="col">
<div class="list-group pl-4">
  <h5 class="font-weight-bold mt-4 mb-2 text-ar-form-text">System</h5>
  <a class="mt-2 text-ar-form-text" href="/instruments">Instruments</a>
  <a class="mt-2 text-ar-form-text" href="/radio">Radio</a>
  <a class="mt-2 text-ar-form-text" href="/power-tools">Power Tools</a>
  <a class="mt-2 text-ar-form-text" href="/fluid">Fluid</a>              

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, to start, you're going to need to add an event handler to those anchors. Then you'll need to find the `h5` that is a sibling to the clicked anchor. Check out http://api.jquery.com for the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an event listener for click on the **a** element. See: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Then inside the function, you can use `this` to refer to the element clicked, and use `https://api.jquery.com/parent/` and `https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/` to find the element you need. Then use `text()` to access to its text value `https://api.jquery.com/text/`.